# Targeting HTML Label for CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to directly style `<label>` but based on value "black"

The html is output by a Wordpress plugin and the `<label>` has a #before selector which I would like to target for changing and icon color. However I wish to change the icon color multiple times based on the radio value .. In the case of value="black" I wish to change the icon to black.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
<div class="mspc-text-wrapper">
   <strong class="mspc-attribute-title">Black</strong>
   <div class="mspc-radio ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="pa_colour" value="black">
      <label>
      ::before
      ::after
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by " the <label> has a #before selector "?

Comment: `input[value="black"] + label`? Hard to tell what you're talking about beyond that.

Comment: I have edited the html to show the selectors .. i can target the :before or ::after selector to add css stying .. however i cannot seem to find a way to target it based on the value of the input as there is no parenthesis between the 2

Comment: BTW, your `label` should have a `for` attribute whose value is the same as an ID attribute of the form element it labels.

Comment: So are you saying that  .mspc-radio input[value="black"] +label::after   would work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select it using the **adjacent sibling selector** `+` like this:

```
input[value=black] + label::before
```

```css
label::before { content: '::before'; } /* just so the result is visible */ 
label::after { content: '::after'; } /* just so the result is visible */ 

input[value=black] + label::before { color: red; }
input[value=black] + label::after { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="mspc-text-wrapper">
   <strong class="mspc-attribute-title">Black</strong>
   <div class="mspc-radio ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="pa_colour" value="black">
      <label>
      
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A perfect answer and explanation. Thank you so much !